# Discord.js 14 how to show commands in the command list filtered by user role?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, roles

it's possible to do that i wrote in the title. i already load the commands when the bot it's ready but i want to only show to users the commands depending on his role, thanks in advance

```
// loading all commands example
CommandList.forEach((command) => {
      commandData.push(
        command.data.toJSON() as {
          name: string;
          description?: string;
          type?: number;
          options?: APIApplicationCommandOption[];
        },
      );
    });

    const response = (await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(BOT.user?.id || "missing token", process.env.GUILD_ID as string),
      {
        body: commandData,
      },
    )) as [];

    logger.debug(`Successfully reloaded ${response.length} application (/) commands.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `default_member_permissions` property

In this code, `8` is `Administrator` permission bitfield so administrators only can execute this command.

```js
const command = {
  name: "sample",
  description: "sample command",
  default_member_permissions: "8"
}
```

[Permissions bitfield docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions)